# Activity Unit Testing holding visual results

Tags: android-activity, android, android-testing

I'm trying to test an Activity. This Activity houses a fragment which contains a listview. I am passing in a object (which is generated from the database) to be displayed within the listview.

I would like to perform this as a test so that I can fill the database with dummy data and just hand off the object to be displayed to the Activity. My problem is that Unit tests aren't really setup to let me play with and visually inspect my fragment with the dummy data. The tests just run and close the app right away.

Can anyone make any recommendations about how they would go about testing this? Or is my only option to create a test database and just use this database in the application, i.e. not using the testing framework.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you look at a UI testing frameworks like [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) which lets one test that UI elements have certain values - for example that a TextEdit contains certain text.